# Unable to set ContextClassLoader in spark shell

Tags: scala, apache-spark, classloader

I am using spark shell(1.6) which uses `TranslatingClassLoader`.

```
scala> Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader 
res13: 
ClassLoader = org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$TranslatingClassLoader@23c767e6
```

For some reason I want to use another class loader, but when I do

```
val myclassloader = // create my own classloader 
Thread.currentThread.setContextClassLoader(myclassloader)
```

The `setContextClassLoader` doesn't seem to work. I still get a `TranslatingClassLoader`:

```
scala> Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader 
res13: 
ClassLoader = org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$TranslatingClassLoader@23c767e6
```

In my previous Java project I can change class loader without problem. Could I know why the above method couldn't change class loader in spark shell?  How can i achieve it?